# How can I use separate domains for single pages?

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I'm  setting up a wordpress site with a domain of let's say "domain.com".
On that site there are Pages like "domain.com/productA" and "domain.com/productB", which are also linked to by the main menu.

I also own the domains "productA.com" and "productB.com"

What I want to achieve is that when a visitor navigates to the productA page through the menu, that the address bar displays "productA.com".
The same should happen when a visitor types "productA.com" in the address bar.

I know that some of this is possible with multisite and domain mapping, but the product pages should still be conained in the main site, sharing things like header and menu, which would be complicated using multisite, or am I wrong?`

Lastly: Does this even make sense? Does this have any positive or negative effects on SEO? Would you advise just redirecting to the main domain?

Comment: This is extremely bad idea in my opinion, unless there's a **very** good reason to do this _(I can't think of any)_. This does not only have a negative effect on SEO, it destroys SEO completely. Different domains are all considered as different sites, have their own SEO, search engine ranks, visitors _etc_, this would probably triple your costs, work and SEO optimization **+** it hurts badly your rank in search engines because 3 sites with smaller visitors count ranks worse than one site with excellent optimization and bigger visitors count. There are probably even more reasons to avoid this.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with @N00b 100%. Depending on what the site is designed to achieve, I find subdomains more professional looking than path-based names. SEO for the sake of SEO is a bad approach, simply because there may be cases where SEO is not a concern (such as internal use only apps for a business with employees working remotely). Do you have more specifics about your plans for the project? Maybe a multi-site installation would be a good fit?

Comment: Ok more specific, the product example is maybe not the best: in reality the client is a doctor, the domain is his name and the additional domains for the subpages are areas he specialises in. For example "haemorrhoids.xx" or "cellulite.xx". He wants to give some general information about the topic on those sites, so they are not really written in an advertising style (hence the separate domains), but they should be included in his main site and use the same theme and menu.

Comment: I agree with @Mike on this one - SEO is not a concern in every case. However, I would personally avoid multiple domains (`PS! different domains & subdomains != same thing` and I understood that you're talking about different domains, not subdomains), especially if all the content falls into same category (medicine, doctor _etc_). For example cellulite.doctorname.com still gives the information about the topic but it also helps to advertise / gain visitors trust for the doctor. In the end, you'll do what you think is the best but I wouldn't use *different domains* for same category topics.

Comment: That makes @N00b's original comment pretty spot on, then. I admit, I misread the question. For whatever reason, I saw "ProductA.domain.com" and "ProductB.domain.com", which is why I went the subdomain direction. Had I read the actual words on the screen, I would have sided with N00b from the outset.

Comment: Thanks guys. So would you advise on just redirecting? The domains for the medicinal areas are actually quite good and my client wants to use them in some way.